# Запятая перед "прежде чем" и "почему"

Tags: запятые

Нужна помощь с расстановкой запятых.
"Она замолчала, прежде чем осознала(,) почему" или "Она замолчала прежде, чем осознала почему"?

Answer (score 1):

Союз "прежде чем" может расчленяться, тогда "прежде" выделяется интонационно в значении *до указанного момента,* но чаще обособляется весь оборот.

Придаточное у вас состоит из одного союзного слова ("почему"). В таких случаях запятая перед ним не ставится.

Таким образом, у вас может быть два варианта:

> Она замолчала, прежде чем осознала почему.
>   Она замолчала пре́жде, чем осознала почему.

Answer (score 0):

Оба варианта возможны, как уже было сказано, но  выбирается нужный **смысловой оттенок.**

***Она замолчала, прежде чем осознала почему.*** Здесь важно, что она замолчала, а момент времени идет как дополнение.

***Она замолчала пре́жде, чем осознала почему.*** В этом случае подчеркнут именно момент времени.